# MySQL Query to get max or min of date depending on conditions

Tags: mysql

i have below table.Objective is : I want to get new date group by ID column. ID might have multiple dates unique to each parentID as mentioned and i would like to create a new date column which will be unique to each ID. If depends on below condition; (flag dependent)

the new date = date of max parentID of an ID if flag of max parentID is "YES"
new date=date of min parentID of an ID if flag  max parentID is "No"

i used case statement with MAX function but not getting desired result.

[image]

Comment: https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-should-i-not-upload-images-of-code-data-errors-when-asking-a-question Provide sample data as textual code-formatted CREATE TABLE + INSERT INTO. Provide desired output for this data with detailed explanations.

Comment: Could you please clarify if your question affects MySQL or SAP HANA as you've tagged both?

Comment: sorry for the confusion Mathias , its mySQL is fine . Since HANA query is almost same as MySQL , i tagged both